# What does time_expiration actually means in biquery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am confused about the time_expiration in bq . suppose i have an expiration of 7 days. what will actually happens after 7 days.

Comment: If you have it on a table, then the table will be deleted after 7 days.

Answer (score 0):

The BigQuery table older data will automatically deleted after 7 days.

> Document Link:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-storage

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-tables

Answer (score 0):

time_expiration is one of the best practice you might want to use in BQ since the data will automatically deteled after it passed specific time set. And I think it's best to implement in staging environment since people tend to forget what they build in staging.

But in the end, it's up to your specific use case